# Error "Unable to open Jupyter Notebook: Port 8888 is already in use"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, port

I am getting following error when I run Jupyter Notebook:

```
(base) C:\Users\ramne>jupyter notebook
[I 01:19:00.648 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
```

And when I do netstat -ano | find Str "8888" , I get the following:

```
C:\Users\ramne>netstat -ano | findStr "8888"
TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16024
TCP    [::1]:8888             [::]:0                 LISTENING       16024
```

I don't know what the default connection of port 8888 is or what its behavior should be like. How do I fix this error so I can open Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The port 8888 is used almost exclusively by Jupyter, and the fact that it's in use indicates more than anything that you have another Jupyter session already running. I'm 99% certain you can just kill the task that's using it, or you can run

```
jupyter notebook list
```

to see current notebooks. And as mentioned in the other answer you can run

```
jupyter notebook --port 8889
```

To run on a different port instead (replace 8889 by any other number you'd like).

Answer (score 3):

use these commads

```
ss -plnt
```

then kill the process number that used the port

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `--port` argument to instruct `jupyter` to start the notebook server on another port.

Use `jupyter notebook --help` command to view the complete list of options.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you can kill the Jupyter notebook process with [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill). 
First display the list of processes with

```
tasklist
```

Then kill the process with:

```
taskkill /F /PID  __process_id_number__
```

Then restart the notebook with:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: If we need a specific port and unlock it, then this response are the best.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy. Just type in the browser 'localhost:8888/tree'. You will get ur notebooks

Answer (score 1):

**issue persisting after reboot and also on virtual env**

(i am on ubuntu 18)

What happen was, I had the notebook also running outside of virtual env as well.

so after doing the stop and deleting the contents in runtime path, it was good after that.

open a new terminal

```
jupyter notebook list
jupyter notebook stop <port num>
jupyter --path
```

delete the contents in path

for good order, check in both environment after stopping the notebook

Comment: works on windows too :)

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to the scripts folder where python is installed

   ```
   C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
   ```
2. a) Check if jupyter notebook is installed:

   ```
   jupyter-notebook.exe
   ```

   b) And not, install it with :

   ```
   pip install notebook

   link to Install : https://jupyter.org/install
   ```
3. Now, in console (cmd) run :

   ```
   jupyter-notebook

   with that it should already work and if it doesn't you may have the 
   same problem as me -> (4)
   ```
4. It happened to me that jupyter does not open in the browser because it was
   configured to have a browser that I did not have, so i changed the configuration
   to a browser that did have. Go to folder **runtime**

   ```
   C:\Users\MiLap\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

   That is the link that jupyter uses to open in your browser. Now Open with 
   your browser :

         nbserver-7660-open.html
   ```

   This is video help me :

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12qmxF337g4