# Jupyter notebook error: The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I just installed Anaconda on y windows 10, but when I try to run the jupyter notebook or jupyter lab by the icon, nothing happend.

1. Tried to run the jupyter by anaconda prompt and got the error: The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
2. Tried to run in several different ports and the error is the same.
3. Tried to kill the task by PID and when I run the jupyter again by promp and it lasts forever and nothing happens
4. Tried to change the browser by manual config and everything is the same
5. Tried to uninstall anaconda and install again several times and boom: Same errors
6. I checked also proxy stuff but everything related to this is unable on my pc
7. Checked firewall and antivirus and also everything seems to be normal

Any other recommendation is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739199/error-unable-to-open-jupyter-notebook-port-8888-is-already-in-use) you may just change port to other, for example:

```
jupyter notebook --port 8889
```

Comment: Hello Andrii, Thanks for your input. I alread did it  with several different ports, but the error persists for those other ports as well.